# Are there any Events or Notifications to get notified when the macOS system is rebooted or OS updated?

Tags: swift, objective-c, macos

Are there any Events or Notifications in Swift/Objective-C to get notified when the macOS system is rebooted or OS updated?
We want to do something after the system restart or when OS is updated.

How to detect or get notify :-

1. When system restarted?
2. When system OS updated?

Comment: Do you want to "do something" in your running app only if your Mac was restarted or updated since your last app run, or do you want your app to start spontaneously after a restart or update to "do something"?

Comment: We want to 'do something' spontaneously by our app when the system OS gets updated